# How to display a view within a template only if there is something to display

Tags: 7, views

I'm looking to embed a view within a template file BUT only if there is something being returned within the view.

I'm using this solution that I saw within the Drupal forum:

```
<?php
 $view = views_get_view_result($name, $display, $args);
 $result = count($view);
?>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 related-articles">
      <?php if ($result) : ?>
        <h3>Related Articles</h3>
        <?php print views_embed_view('related_articles', 'related_articles'); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So is this the right way to check if that view is returning anything? Or am I missing something there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of embedding a view in a template, please consider having your view output a block display, which you can place on your site using the Block System, Panels or Context.

Comment: Jim, well this view: related_articles is outputting as a block. How can I achieve this then?

Comment: Easiest way, go to the Block Administration Page (/admin/structure/block) and find your block in the list.  Use the drop down to add it to the region of your theme that you want, or click configure to get even more options.

Comment: Also to note, in the view, under Advanced, there are other options in the "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR" for the block if needed. Leaving it blank should hide the block if empty.